# why Reloading collection view in another class will cause Fatal Error in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift3, reloaddata, collectionview

I have a collection view in my app that is in one class - I have camera function in another class so I want when I take picture the function execute in collection view class and I want reload data in that collection view but this will cause Fatal Error

```
here is the camera class codes 
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

    let selectedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage

    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(selectedImage,self,nil,nil)


    oneViewController().reloading()

    print("save Image ")

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(3), execute: {

        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)            


    })
```

and here is the oneView Controller reloading function

```
public func reloading() {

    print("OKy")


            viewDidLoad()
            viewWillAppear(true)

            let allPhotosOptions : PHFetchOptions = PHFetchOptions.init()
            allPhotosOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "modificationDate", ascending: true)]
            let allPhotosResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .image, options: allPhotosOptions)
            allPhotosResult.enumerateObjects({ (asset, idx, stop) in

                let arry_img = NSMutableArray()

                self.arry_img.add(asset)
                self.arr_img = arry_img

                self.collview.reloadData()

            })

}
```

Comment: can you please post what is the error message is

Comment: I didn't receive any text just its written Fatal Error

Comment: Why are you calling viewDidLoad and viewViewAppear in reloading function ? simply create one delegate method for your oneView controller and call that delegate when you get selected images.

Comment: its not simple for me to explain I used collection view that reaches gallery photos and the camera button is in another view controller that is in the container view that is in the current view controller and I want when user took the picture reload the collection view but all of the functions should be done again so I used view did load